# Mongo DB Connector for BI - mongosqld - Can't Use ObjectId on database pipeline

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to filter some data through a $match stage in a database pipeline on .drdl file. The stage works fine if I try to match a primitive field like a boolean, but when I try to filter an ObjectId field mongosqld puts quotes on everything and the stage returns 0 documents.

DRDL file:

```
schema:
- db: mydb
  tables:
  - table: cars
    collection: cars
    pipeline: [{"$match":{"maker":{"$in":[ObjectId("599c404e7611234567890000")]}}}]
    columns:
    - Name: _id
      MongoType: bson.ObjectId
      SqlName: _id
      SqlType: varchar
    - Name: maker
      MongoType: bson.ObjectId
      SqlName: maker
      SqlType: varchar
    - Name: active
      MongoType: bool
      SqlName: active
      SqlType: boolean
    - Name: model
      MongoType: string
      SqlName: model
      SqlType: varchar
...
```

In mongosqld debug info I can see that the $match stage was turned into:

```
{"$match":{"maker":{"$in":["ObjectId(\"599c404e7611234567890000\")"]}}}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `{"$match":{"maker":{"$in":[{ "$oid": "599c404e7611234567890000" }]}}}`. I don't have a BI connector spun up right now, but it's likely to support the [Extended JSON Syntax](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) format here

Comment: Hi @NeilLunn, thanks a lot, **that worked**. I will accept this as an answer as soon as you submit it as one. Best regards.